# Permission Error When Specifying NDK Root in Mac

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, setup.py, cocos2d-android

I'm trying to run the setup.py of cocos2dx. I have downloaded the sdk, ndk and apache ant. But whenever I try to link it to the necessary paths, I get this error.

I'm not really sure what this means. How can I get permission? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but anyway... it'll work if you put NDK in `/Users/gamedev/android-ndk-r10e` and adjust environment variables accordingly.

Comment: hi. i already found out my issue. my account has no access to .bash_profile. :) thanks.

Comment: That's great. Btw, accept your own answer then so that it's clear to new visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my account didn't have access to bash_profile.
We can check this by typing `ls -la`

Since my account doesn't have permission to edit bash_profile, I wasn't able to add the path to the ndk, sdk and ant.